# How to use a column named as keyword in a DB2 concat function

Tags: sql, db2, concatenation

So I got this table FOO which has a column of the type VARCHAR and is named COMMENT (which happens to be a reserved keyword).
When I am trying to use it in a CONCAT function in my select the result is NULL.

How can I fix this?

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT('{"NAME":"', NAME), '","COMMENT":"'), COMMENT),'"}')
FROM
    SOMESCHEMA.FOO
```

I also tried to use " or ' around `COMMENT`, but then it is interpreted as a VARCHAR...

2nd I used ` but that happens to print me the following error.

1. [Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  ILLEGAL SYMBOL "`". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE:.

I also tried to add the SCHEMA and the TABLE name in front of the column like:

```
CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT('{"NAME":"', NAME), '","COMMENT":"'), SOMESCHEMA.FOO.COMMENT),'"}')
```

But no luck.

Comment: Can you try `SELECT '{"NAME":"' CONCAT NAME CONCAT '","COMMENT":"' CONCAT COMMENT CONCAT  '"}' FROM ...`? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/intro/src/tpc/db2z_concatenationofstrings.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT('{"NAME":"', NAME
                                  ), '","COMMENT":"'
                           ), "COMMENT"
                    ),
              '"}')
FROM SOMESCHEMA.FOO
```

That is, double quotes only around the column name.

I would find this simpler to read using the infix operator:

```
SELECT '{"NAME":"' CONCAT NAME CONCAT '","COMMENT":"' CONCAT "COMMENT" CONCAT '"}'
FROM SOMESCHEMA.FOO
```

or:

```
SELECT '{"NAME":"' || NAME || '","COMMENT":"' || "COMMENT" || '"}'
FROM SOMESCHEMA.FOO
```

Comment: Now I am feeling dumb :D

Comment: @Spektakulatius . . . Don't feel dumb.  Feel like you have learned something.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like DB2 also accept the ANSI/ISO SQL `||` concatenation:

```
SELECT 
    '{"NAME":"' || NAME || '","COMMENT":"' || COMMENT || '"}'
FROM
    SOMESCHEMA.FOO
```